# SSAS - How to hide branches without leaf from a dimension?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssas

I'm working on a SSAS project.
I created a **DimGeography** dimension to represent Country > Region > Department > City > Store as a Tree. It works well ! However, my tree display all branches without stores.

[image]

So after processing my dimension I can browse all elements even if there is no store in a city (or dept/region/country).

[image]

Any idea to solve that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of separate tables, I would use one view as the base for the dimension with all tables joined together. And if you use inner joins, then the branches without shops would not appear in the view, end hence not in the dimension as well.